# Unit scale coherence in library .blend files

Tags: blend-files

I want to work with libraries to model multiple objects of various sizes.

I have a two libraries .blend files with only a cube in them. The difference between these two files is that the scene's unit is in meters in the first one, and it is in centimeters in the second one, so I have a 1m cube and a 1cm cube.

I don't understand why, when I import (append/link) both of these cubes in a third project, they both are the same size (which is 1 meter), when the second cube is supposed to be one centimeter. Is there a way to do that without having to use the same unit everywhere and zooming in a lot ?